# How to call c# function with out parameter in c++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, activex

I very new to C++.

I have a C# dll which I want to call it in c++ project.

The function in C# I would declare it like this:

```
   public int ShowStringReturn(out string str)
    {
        str = "Message from c#";
        return 0; 
    }
```

Then, I call it in my C++ project :

```
__declspec(dllexport) 
    int ShowStringCSharpReturn (std::string &strOut)
    {
        try
        {  
            String^ str; 
            IngWrapper::Ingressus_Instance->xIMUobject->ShowStringReturn(str);  

            using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal; 
            const char* chars = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str)).ToPointer( );
            strOut = chars; 

            return 0; 
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons::OK,MessageBoxIcon::Error);
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

I can compile it, but when I call the activex dll in my windows form application, i get an error "External component has thrown an exception"
How should I declare and call my function?

Comment: The only things that are really obvious is that you leak the string buffer and that you are playing a very dangerous game by passing a C++ object across DLL boundaries.  Which will blow up when the calling C++ code doesn't use the same DLL version of the CRT as the C++/CLI code.  You'll need to provide a better diagnostic, at least a stack trace.

Comment: We assume that they are using the same version of DLL and CRT. Now the problem is that I failed to convert String^ to std::string. I able to get message return from C#, but when i tried to do conversion, it get an exception.